# form_for syntax problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to generate something like

<% form_for [@user, @name], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

in my rails template, but this syntax is not allowed. What is a right syntax for this situation. Thanks!

Comment: what is @name? is it attribute of user?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Maybe more information would help. Is there a specific URL you are looking to generate? What controller is this view used in? Are @user and @name both objects? Does @user have potentially many @names? - thats what rails will try to guess by that syntax.

Comment: i want to do "nested controller", user is nested in name. I know, that <% form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> works and <% form_for [@user, @name] do |f| %> works, but i need to combine it...

Comment: __And show your controller action for that form__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your syntax is ok. You've just forgotten equal `=` sign:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @name], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

and also you need to manage your routes as well

```
resources :users do
  resources :names
end
```

And you need to specify `@user` and `@name` in your controller action:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @name = @user.names.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the @name is attribute of @user, then following code will work.

```
<% form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

see more about [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: Sorry for confusion, in my case name is nested in used. I know that <% form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> works and <% form_for [@name,@user] do |f| %> works, but i need to combine it...

Comment: so what is the issue or error occurs in form_for [@user,@name]? is this a has_many association?

Comment: i get undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class